# Selecting drives for a windows system image

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, disk-image, windows-7-backup

Hello im trying to create a system image of my OS drive on my PC using the "Backup and Restore (Windows 7)". However when I go to make the image, It automatically checks the (D:) drive, which I can't remove.
[image: Image of the backup software]

I was just wondering if anyone could help me out as to why this might be so that I can uncheck it because it is a large drive that I don't want to include in my image. And while some software in installed onto this drive, none of it is "required for Windows to run" as the dialog says.

The following is a screenshot of my partition setup.
[image: Image of the backup software]

Comment: Do you know if your swap file or hibernation file are on the D: drive?

Comment: @cybernard I have set the page file to only be stored on the C drive, i then restarted the PC, unfortunately this did not solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Windows *Backup and Restore* has some intrinsic limitations. You have more options, such as selecting specific drives or even certain  partitions on a drive, with third-party software such as [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) and [many alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/).

These applications often allow creation of rescue media so that in the event that there are HD issues, you can boot and restore from USB or CD.